# React serves default content for incorrect paths

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I used create-react-app to play with react. I noticed that no matter what I type in after localhost:3000/ (which is the default url on dev machine) I always get the content from localhost:3000

This means I cannot access images so that sort of means I can't really do anything with it.

Is this a bug or is it some awesome new feature that I just don't understand? How can this be switched off?

Comment: Are you using the Webpack dev server with [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)?

Comment: How can I find out if I'm using it? I think create-react-app is "hiding" all of that stuff from me. I could probably "eject" the application, but then what's the point of using create-react-app?

Comment: Yes, CRA uses it. It just sends `index.html` for all requests that give a 404 response. If you add an image to the `public` folder, you can use that image as you would expect.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing into right direct. I change the flag in the config file (which I should not be doing) and I get 404 now. Copying the file to public folder works as well. I can see that react ppl recommend importing images - which I believe copies the files to the right place, but I didn't test that yet.

Comment: If you add an answer I'll mark it as correct. One more question. I deployed that page to production just for fun. It is served by nginx and I can see the same behavior with exception that hard reload causes 404. So if I type mydomain.com/test - loads index, if I hit Ctrl+F5 (in Chrome) I get 404. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you using React Router or another front end router? In that case the routing will be handled by the browser, so you need to make sure that all routes (`/test`, `/test/another`, ...) all loads the `index.html` file so the browser can take it from there.

Comment: And yes, if you import an image (`import img from './image.png'`) that will be handled by Webpack and put in the final `build` folder for you. There might be use cases where importing the image is not feasible, so then you can put it in the `public` folder, but importing it is often recommended for most cases.

Comment: Are you using React Router or another front end router? Nothing. Just created the app and loaded to the server. I'm suspecting the service worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create React App uses [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) for the `webpack-dev-server`, which means that all requests that give a 404 response will fall back to load the `index.html` file.

If you e.g. add an image to the `public` folder, you can see that the image takes precedence over the `index.html` file.

You can also import the image with the help of Webpack and use the import as `src` in your code, and Webpack will make sure the image ends up in the final `build` folder for you.

```
import img from './image.png';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
render() {
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
}
```

for more information please refer [Adding Assets Outside of the Module System](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#user-content-adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system)